# How to add a white stripe to a tire

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders

In a car model, I have a tire object that is using a very simple BSDF where the only value that's not left default is the base color, set to grey. I would like to ask someone more experienced how I could modify the cycles shader to add a white stripe to the tire like the ones old cars had. I tried playing with the ColorRamp node, but without success.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This is a frequently asked question: [Add different materials to different parts of a mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh). Usually you want a soft transition between both shaders so you'll have to unwrap it (project from view should do it in this case), then just paint a black and white mask, use a mix shader node and plug the mask into the factor as described in the second answer of the linked question.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, your advice, in combination with the linked question solved it for me. I voted to close this question.